# Cakephp Heroku plugin path error

Tags: php, cakephp, heroku

I have a Cakephp app running on Heroku but having trouble loading plugins. This all works on my local dev machine but when I push to Heroku Cake cannot find a plugin I have defined. The error message indicates it's looking for plugins in "/app/app/Plugin" instead of "/app/Plugin". How would I correct the path on Heroku without breaking my local paths?

Error: ElasticSearchIndex.ElasticSearchIndexableBehavior could not be found.

Error: Create the class ElasticSearchIndexableBehavior below in file: /app/app/Plugin/ElasticSearchIndex/Model/Behavior/ElasticSearchIndexableBehavior.php

StackTrace:
[image]

Comment: Try to put all third party Libraries in outer vendors directory

Comment: is there any way that you can simulate Heroku paths in localhost? Some configuration or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I am an idiot. The issue was not with Heroku or CakePHP it was the fact that I cloned the git repos for the plugins instead of adding them as submodules. This resulted in the plugins not actually being present when pushed to Heroku. The confusing part of "/app/app" was because app code is located inside "/app" on the Heroku instance so it was looking at the correct path the whole time.